# Does UnityEngine.CustomeYieldInstruction works in a seperate thread?

Tags: c#, multithreading, unity-game-engine, thread-safety, coroutine

As we know coroutines works in the main thread and i read somewhere that by implementing customyieldinstruction you can wait for something to complete in a separate thread. Is this true? Will it not freeze or slows down my app??

I've tried yield return and it freezes my app

For Reference , does the code mentioned will work on seperate thread?

https://jacksondunstan.com/articles/3746

I want to load some data from server (about 80 to 90 images and text) and i want to do it squentially (wait for first 10 to load completely) but my app freezes as it gets yield return

Comment: Well it's all kind of moot now that Unity supports `Task` so you should be using `async/await` for this sort of thing

Comment: Thanks for the answer
Does async/await works on seperate thread in Unity ?

Comment: Yes for compute-bound operations that you start with `Task.Run()`